# How can i make this function accept phone numbers and email together?

Tags: php, prestashop

I have this function which accept only email and i need edit this to accept email and phone numbers like this +970598465 or 0598454879.

```
public static function isEmail($email)
{
    return !empty($email) && preg_match(Tools::cleanNonUnicodeSupport('/^[a-z\p{L}0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^`{}|~_-]+[.a-z\p{L}0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^`{}|~_-]*@[a-z\p{L}0-9]+(?:[.]?[_a-z\p{L}0-9-])*\.[a-z\p{L}0-9]+$/ui'), $email);
}
```

Comment: I would think that it would be easier to implement a similar function that is specifically for phone numbers. Though there are regex examples of phone number validation you will need to adapt them to match the phone number length/format of the countries that your code needs to support.

Comment: Yes you're right i see them here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107207/validate-phone-number-using-php) but actually i can't add this code  `^\(?\+?([0-9]{1,4})\)?[-\. ]?(\d{10})$
` to my function, so please if you know how to add it tell me please.

Comment: Like @MrGlass suggested, add another function called `isPhoneNumber` and add your code, then when you want to check your input do this `if (!isEmail("foo") || !isPhoneNumber("foo"))`

Comment: Yes, i did that guys, thanks!